# mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FIELDS FROM `inventory_stock_1`'

Tags: magento2, error

I'm exporting database from Magento 2.4.2 with this command:

```
mysqldump --single-transaction DBUSER --triggers | sed -e 's/DEFINER[ ]*=[ ]*[^*]*\*/\*/' | gzip > FILENAME.`date +"%Y%m%d"`.sql.gz
```

I get this error:

> mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FIELDS FROM `inventory_stock_1`':
> View 'DBNAME.inventory_stock_1' references invalid table(s) or
> column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use
> them (1356)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a view table `inventory_stock_1` for your catalog in the database.

Run this command in your DB SQL. Make sure to update 3 things in the below query `dbusername`, `localhost` and `dbname`.

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`dbusername`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY INVOKER VIEW `inventory_stock_1`  AS  select distinct `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`website_id` AS `website_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`stock_id` AS `stock_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`qty` AS `quantity`,`legacy_stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,`product`.`sku` AS `sku` from (`dbname`.`cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status` join `dbname`.`catalog_product_entity` `product` on((`legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` = `product`.`entity_id`)));
```

But You need elevated permissions to use the `CREATE ALGORITHM` bit. If you get a permissions error then try creating a view using the below command:

```
CREATE
OR REPLACE
VIEW `inventory_stock_1` AS select
    distinct `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`website_id` AS `website_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_id` AS `stock_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`qty` AS `quantity`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,
    `product`.`sku` AS `sku`
from
    ( `cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status`
join `catalog_product_entity` `product` on
        (( `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` = `product`.`entity_id` )));
```

Comment: Should this be safe to try in production environment as I'm not able to create a working backup from the database currently...?